# Print only the numeric values in list separated by comma and space in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, printing

I have just started learning python and I am trying to print all the elements in list without the square brackets. The elements have to be separated by a comma and a space, kind of like this-> **1, 2, 3, 4, 5** 
Just so that I make it clear there should be no space before the comma.
I have tried this and it works but I need a more efficient way of doing it.

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in l:
    print(str(i)+", ",end="")
print("\b\b ")
```

P.S: Python Version: 3.7.3

Answer (score 3):

You can unpack the list and use a custom seperator

```
print(*l, sep=', ')
```

You can even include the ending as well if you'd like

```
print(*l, sep=', ', end='\b\b ')
```

Comment: the `\b\b will remove the last 2 chars, which in your case wilil be the 5 and the space, i think the OP was using it cause in their code they would end up writting an extra comma and space on the last item to they wanted to remove them

Comment: @ChrisDoyle - it seemed fine when I [tried it](https://ideone.com/FpvGBL)? I noticed it might have been because of the end the op was using which is why my original answer omitted it

Comment: I think it depends on the console/terminal which outputs it. In your link it puts 2 squares at the end as the terminal doesnt know what to do. If you try it on repl. it corectly removes the lst two chars https://repl.it/repls/AstonishingMoccasinDaemons

Comment: @ChrisDoyle - ah ok good to know! I'm on mobile atm so didn't have a terminal to play around in

Comment: I added an answer using join but in it i have referred to your answer as its way cleaner and doesnt need to convert the ints to strings first.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle - I'd already upvoted it since it'd be a better option if you need to assign it to a variable instead of printing

Comment: Thanks for the help @Sayse Your 1st solution works fine there is no need to use the other one with the ending.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the join method of string to join string together with a specific seperator, we need to use a list comprehension to conver the ints to strs. but the answer from @Sayse is much cleaner and less complicated and doesnt require you to convert your ints to strings first.

```py
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(f'{", ".join([str(i) for i in l])}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: You dont need the outer f string, the join you have will suffice

Comment: haha oh yeah, f-strings are my default way to write any string these days. so its there by default rather than needed :)

Comment: As i said i am a beginner and i like Sayse 's  solution too but just for the sake of curiosity i was trying to understand how does your code work? What is the use of "f" there and i tried replacing it with another alphabet (coz i thought that's a temporary variable) but then it gave invalid syntax error. Kindly can you explain please? @chris-doyle

Comment: In python 3.6 and onwards there exists f-strings which allow you to put variables or expressions inside your string. You can read more here http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/03/13/python-3-an-intro-to-f-strings/